# Android reverse image search

Tags: android, image, search, google-image-search

In my project i need to include searchs to a API Rest to query with a url that points to a jpg picture and it returns a list of urls with similar pictures.

[Google Images](https://images.google.com/) performs via web like i am looking for, but the clients for Android that [i have found (github projects)](https://github.com/tomazsh/image-search-android-app) they work simply with an input text.

The simplest code would be something  as below:

```
String inputUrlPic = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/03/14/20/13/dog-287420__340.jpg";
String[] returnedUrlPictures = null; //list of returned pictures similars to inputUrlPic

ReverseImageApi reverseImageApi = new ReverseImageApi();//My desired Api object

returnedUrlPictures = reverseImageApi.findSimilarPicturesFromUrl(inputUrlPic); //Ok, it would be an asynctask
```

So, my question is, exists a API or an Android client API to perform in this way?

Comment: To avoid the question being closed without being answered, please refer to [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, i've improved the content

Comment: You need to include a Minimal, Verifiable code example

Comment: Thanks, i've added some code

Comment: You need to include a question

Comment: Thanks, i've added a question